# Functions Property Question

Tags: function

Is this proposition true?

For all functions  *f*
*f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)*.

If yes then why? If no then what are those special functions called and what property do they have?

EDIT:
Wow i think floor/celing functions do not hold the property.? I can think of counterexamples but could somebody please prove this. But what are the functions that hold this property called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention a function *f* for which:

```
f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)
```

Such a function is called a [Homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism), and it can be defined on certain algebraic structures. In this case *+* is a special binary function that maps *a* and *b* onto an element of the same domain.

Obviously not all functions are homomorphisms, as others have already shown you.

Answer (score 0):

In procedural programming this is not true, since arbitrary functions can have arbitrary side-effects.

For example, you could have a global counter that is incremented every time you call f() and added to the return value.

Comment: Even in purely functional languages, not every function is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Does log(a+b) = log(a) + log(b)?

Comment: another simple (counter)example is f(x) = x^2.

Answer (score 0):

No.

They are called linear if also f(k * a) = k * f(a).

In general such a function is called a homomorphism, but this is not limited to addition.